# ld: library not found for -lJGProgressHUD

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I cloned the project and tried to build it but got stuck due to the following error, can you tell me how to deal with it?

```
ld: library not found for -lJGProgressHUD
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have done pods install, but the error exists.

Need some help in solving this issue.

Comment: Have you opened .xcodeproj file instead of the .xcworkspace ?

Comment: opened the .xcworkspace

Comment: tried to do a project 'clean' ?

Comment: did the project clean by pressing Cmd+Shift+K.

Comment: by cloning the project you mean you've added JGProgressHUD in podfile then run pod install ?

Comment: it ws already there. then i did run pod install as well.

Comment: when you look in 'Linked Framework and Libraries' is it listed there ?

Comment: under build settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95162/discussion-between-lakesh-and-hal9000).

Answer (score 0):

Well, That's what worked for me :

- Open Build settings
- Search for Other Linker flags
- remove -l"Pods-XXXLibrary"

Thats it !